# Why history.push('/profile') is redirecting in this url /current-url#/profile?

Tags: redux, react-redux

Can you help me fix this. It's not redirecting and the url change but it's adding the value in history push instead of replacing the current url.
history.js

```
import createHistory from 'history/createHashHistory'
export default createHistory()
```

action.js

```
export function signoutUser(){
    return {
        type: SIGN_OUT
    }
}
```

actionUser.js

```
export function signOutUser() {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(signoutUser());
    history.push('/profile');
  };
}
```

```
  <BrowserRouter history={history}>
          <div>
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/sign-in" render={props => <Auth><Page {...props} /></Auth>} />
              <Route exact path="/sign-up" render={props => <Auth><PageTwo {...props} /></Auth>}  />
              <Route path="/profile" render={props => <Auth><Profile{...props} /></Auth>} />
            </Switch>
          </div>
        </BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: What is signoutUser?

Comment: Is an action.js basically is just calling the dispatch type.

Comment: I already did @HMR please check

Comment: My guess is that you dispatch `SIGN_OUT ` and then try to go to `/profile` but `Auth` is detecting you're not signed in so replacing the location with sign in.

Comment: hmm make sense thanks @HMR. I try to fix the logic in Auth.